# Python Unicode Error With % Operator

Tags: python, unicode

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but with this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Foo(object):
    CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP = {"CAD":'$', "USD":'$', "GBP" : "£"}

    def bar(self, value, symbol="GBP"):
        result = u"%s%s" % (self.CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP[symbol], value)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    print f.bar(unicode("19.00"))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print f.bar(unicode("19.00"))
  File "test.py", line 7, in bar
    result = u"%s%s" % (self.CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP[symbol], value)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is with Python 2.7.6

PS - I get that there are libraries like [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) for formmatting things as currency, my question is more with respect to unicode strings and the `%` operator.

Comment: Could you use the [new way of formatting strings](https://pyformat.info/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the strings you're inserting are Unicode too.

```
CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP = {"CAD":u'$', "USD":u'$', "GBP" : u"£"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to insert a non-unicode string into a unicode string. You just have to make the values in `CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP` unicode objects.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Foo(object):
    CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP = {"CAD":u'$', "USD":u'$', "GBP" : u"£"}  # this line is the difference

    def bar(self, value, symbol="GBP"):
        result = u"%s%s" % (self.CURRENCY_SYMBOL_MAP[symbol], value)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    print f.bar(unicode("19.00"))
```